# how to apply tf

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,I'm a beginner in ROS and using ROS INDIGO. I'm trying to apply transformation to my odometry data but when I went through it I got confused about how it is to be implemented.can anybody please help me to make out the concept in doing transformation to my odometry data  inorder to use it with gmapping ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225869/how-to-apply-tf/) by [niel](https://answers.ros.org/users/25707/niel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check the [ros navigation tutorial on this.](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) It describes publishing odom in detail.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2